# How to dynamically exclude spring boot configuration classes in component tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I work with a bunch of Spring Boot applications.  They have a bunch of configuration classes that run at startup.  Each application can exclude some classes from auto-configuration with the "`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=...`" mechanism.

For instance, one of the applications has this annotation:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class, CassandraRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
```

These are excluded because this application doesn't use those frameworks.  However, this application DOES use Hazelcast, so it does not include the "`HazelcastAutoConfiguration.class`" in this list.

Each application also has "component" tests that lie somewhere between unit tests and integration tests.  They use the following annotations at a minimum:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

The point of a component test is to test the entire application, but with network dependencies mocked and stubbed.  In this case, we have to prevent the application from making a Hazelcast connection.  If I temporarily add "`HazelcastAutoConfiguration.class`" to the exclusion list, that makes the component test work, but of course, the application will then fail to work.

I need some way to make the application exclude the Hazelcast configurator in the component test, but include it in normal operation.

I believe there are multiple ways I could get this done.  Could someone detail my options?  I believe one of those options is "profiles", but I'm not sure how that would work here.

**Update**:

Initially, I thought I could make this happen by doing this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
            properties = {"spring.autoconfigure.exclude = " +
"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastAutoConfiguration"})
```

But I found it was still calling `HazelcastClientConfiguration`.  Then I discovered that this configuration class is also referenced in `CacheAutoConfiguration`, so I added that class to the exclude list.  That sort of worked, but now I get:

```
IllegalStateException: No CacheResolver specified, and no bean of type CacheManager found. Register a CacheManager bean or remove the @EnableCaching annotation from your configuration.
```

Am I at the end of my property-driven rope?  Is there a simpleish way to get through this with test properties or annotation properties on the `@SpringBootTest` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Use a profile for tests by annotating the tests with `@ActiveProfiles("test")` and annotate the configuration classes with `@Profile("!test")`.

For library configuration classes you could mock the bean:

```
@MockBean
private SomeClass someClass;
```

Here is some more on this topic: https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean

Comment: Actually, I think I was able to get this done in a simpler fashion. It will be a few mins before I can be certain, but by simply adding a "spring.autoconfigure.exclude = " setting to the "properties" property of the @SpringBootTest annotation, I think this will do what I need.

Comment: As you said, there are several ways to achieve this.

Comment: It got me closer, but not all the way there.